# Any cheap Technic sets with a good variety of parts?

Tags: technic, building, gbc

I want to start building a module like [GBC Miniloop 01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUjcYVaulDM), but when I check the part list some are very hard to find. How should I get started with miniloops?

BTW, I got a very big set, Bucket Wheel Excavator 42055, and wanted to be able to do MOC's based on the parts in there. There are still many parts not included that I need for building this small GBC Mini loop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The parts in the model in that video look pretty generic, it appears to be mostly bricks, which are easily substituted for other colors or even shapes. If you need a quantity of a certain piece, you can try Bricklink.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara thanks. but parts like 3937 rocker bearing 1*2 seems hard.

Comment: Rocker bearing 1*2 appears in nearly 1000 sets
https://brickset.com/parts/design-3937

Comment: You are in luck.  [PV Productions](http://pv-productions.com/product/lego-gbc-15-42055-building-instructions/) has instructions for building a huge GBC setup out of the pieces in the 42055.

Comment: @chicks this saves me a lot of money and time to collect parts and use what i have thanks again !

Comment: 42055 strikes me as being an excellent parts pack by itself - I also built a GBC module using parts of it (just a small subset), and other have too

Answer (score 4):

In answer to your question "I want to build a Great Ball Contraption and have [LEGO set 42055](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42055-1), what other LEGO sets do I need to buy?" the answer is: None. You've got all the bits needed, even a motor.

[Instructions to make a Great Ball Contraption from LEGO set 42055](https://pv-productions.com/product/lego-gbc-15-42055-building-instructions/) are available for purchase for about USD25, and [advertisement for the instructions can be see on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mj7qMq-Jh4). The are other instructions available - like https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/design.page?idModel=140147

The PV instructions are just one of dozens of [alternative 42055 builds](https://web2.rebrickable.com/sets/42055-1/bucket-wheel-excavator/#alt_builds).